# Prism UnityBootstrapper IUnityContainer Resolve returns an Object as opposed to DependencyObject

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

Prism UnityBootstrapper IUnityContainer Resolve returns an Object as opposed to DependencyObject.

Also the parameters have changed.

Previously we just to needed to pass a generic parameter, but now there are 3.

Examples on GitHub still don't reflect these changes.

I wanted to know why was this changed and its benefits compared to previous implementation ?

I don't see any generic Resolve method on IUnityContainer.

[image: IUnityContainer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with Prism as this is specific to the Unity container behavior.  Second, IUnityContainer.Resolve has always returned an object.  This has never changed.  If you want a strongly typed return type then use `Resolve<T>`.

Comment: I don't see any generic Resolve method on IUnityContainer, question updated with screenshot.

Comment: It's an extension method and you need to add `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity`.

Comment: Thats what I was missing, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The generic resolve is an extension method and resides in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions`, so add

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
```

to your code and

```
var anObjectOfMyType = _container.Resolve<MyType>();
var anInterfaceImplementation = _container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

should work.